# Batch File creates unwanted folder

Tags: batch-file

I am running into an issue with a batch process I wrote. It is supposed to create a folder with named with today's "date-time". It ran properly for weeks, and is now creating 2 folders instead of 1. 1 has the date, one has the time.

Being a novice in batch scripting I am unsure what is causing the process to create 2 folders instead of 1. ("FilePath" below is actually a valid directory that I replaced for privacy)

```
cd C:\FilePath
set folder=%date:~4,2%%date:~7,2%%date:~10,4%"-"%time:~0,2%%time:~3,2%
mkdir %folder%
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Sounds like `folder` has spaces in it, so it looks like you need `mkdir "%folder%"`.

Comment: I wondering about sometimes you're using %% and sometimes only 1 %

Comment: THANK YOU!!! I knew it was something simple. Tested and works perfect, thanks again!

Comment: just curious: why do you use double quotes (`"-"`)?

Comment: @ColinFluegel No problem :) I went ahead an made it an answer.

Answer (score 2):

If `%folder` has spaces in it, then `mkdir` will split that into multiple new folders.

Instead, you want:

```
mkdir "%folder%"
```

This way, it will create one directory as intended.

Comment: +1: Another option is to remove the spaces. `set "folder=%folder: =%"`

Comment: or replace them with a zero `set "folder=%folder: =0%` - may look nicer in the directory.